# OpenCV 3.02 + text module + Tesseract 3.05 runtime error: Tesseract not found

Tags: opencv, ocr, tesseract, opencv3.2

I correctly installed OpenCV 3.2 using cmake to generate it from source code as in this [link](http://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-windows/), installed Tesseract 3.05 and leptonica from [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract). Both work correctly on these sample example [RedEyeRemover](https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/tree/master/RedEyeRemover) for OpenCV and [opencv-tesseract](https://github.com/xuwangyin/opencv-tesseract/blob/master/opencv-tesseract.cpp) for testing both together, target project x64 VS2017. But then when applied to end-to-end text recognition demo (Platform toolset VS2015 v140) provided by opencv, I have no error in compilation but get tesseract not found in runtime.

[image: Tesseract not found]

```
    double t_r = (double)getTickCount();
    Ptr<OCRTesseract> ocr = OCRTesseract::create();
    cout << "TIME_OCR_INITIALIZATION = " << ((double)getTickCount() - t_r) * 1000 / getTickFrequency() << endl;
    string output;
```

It occurs at **OCRTesseract::create()** level.

What can be the reason if I didn't get any compilation error? It's linked to opencv_text module.

Comment: i want to try help you step by step

Comment: ok please create the chat room and put the link, as I don't know how to do.

Comment: as i know it will be available after some comments

Comment: `Could NOT find GIF (missing: GIF_LIBRARY GIF_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Found JPEG: C:/Users/Jihed Mestiri/Anaconda2/Library/lib/jpeg.lib  
Found ZLIB: C:/Users/Jihed Mestiri/Anaconda2/Library/lib/z.lib (found version "1.2.8") 
Found PNG: C:/Users/Jihed Mestiri/Anaconda2/Library/lib/png.lib (found version "1.6.17") 
Found TIFF: C:/Users/Jihed Mestiri/Anaconda2/Library/lib/tiff.lib (found version "4.0.6") 
Found PkgConfig: C:/cygwin64/bin/pkg-config.exe (found version "0.29.1") 
Checking for module 'libwebp'
  No package 'libwebp' found
Configuring done`  I couldn't put all the output

Comment: I don't know how it's getting them from Anaconda.. I cannot remove that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152157/discussion-between-sturkmen-and-sarah-m).

Comment: `31>C:/Program Files/opencv/opencv_contrib-3.2.0/modules/text/src/precomp.hpp(51): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tesseract/baseapi.h': No such file or directory 34>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\..\lib\Release\opencv_text320.lib' 45>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\..\lib\Release\opencv_datasets320.lib'`

Comment: do you have tesseract305.dll? when I run RedEyeRemover code I get tesseract305.dll not found as runtime error

Comment: put `leptonica-1.74.4.dll`,`tesseract305.dll` and files *.xml *.xml.gz from [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/text/samples) in the exe dir

Comment: what exe dir to put them in?

Comment: same dir with your exe

Comment: please check my message in chat room.

Answer (score 1):

just posting an answer stating there is some practical information in [chat session](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152157/discussion-between-sturkmen-and-sarah-m)
about compiling leptonica tesseract and OpenCV

Comment: Thank you for your help in the chat room!Now, tesseract3.05.01 opencv3.2 and leptonica1.74.7 are working all together. However, the project I have a problem in, which is same as text-example-end_to_end_recognition sample, didn't work for me when executing it from its .exe file (closes directly after running it)